# Issues putting Cloudfront infront of ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-application-load-balancer

I want to have CloudFront infront of a load balancer for a web app (built with VueJs and Nuxt). but the issue is that I get DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN when going to the Cloudfront Url {key}.cloudfront.net.

I found that it might have with Certificates to do, I have the same certificate on bout ALB and CloudFront, but CloudFront certificate is stored in N.virginia and ALB is in Ireland which is suppose to give me this issue.

My question is how it should be setup to work.
Today ALB has listeners
Https listener on port 443 with certificate (located in Ireland region)
Http listener on port 80 which redirect all request to Https.

The ALB is publically available therefore I wanted the Http to Https redirect.

Comment: Can you share you cloudfront settings (especially the certificate and alternate domain name settings)?

Comment: Can show everything here. 
But I have 4 registered certificate.
Ireland: 
Cert A 
Cert B
N.Virginia:
Cert A 
Cert B
I need the cert In N.Viriginia for the Cloud Front cant use the Cert from ireland

Comment: Hey, Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: No, will update if i find a good solution but seems like no good solution so far